# Find parent element data value and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph

I made a simple horizontal graph chart and use jQuery and data-value in html to set the width of each bar and this part works fine. I am stuck trying to display the data-value inside each graph bar. The following jQuery code displays the last graph bar's data-value which is 22% in every graph bar. How can I display each graph bar's data-value properly?

HTML Code

```
<div class="graph-bar-bg">
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="78"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

jQuery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.graph-bar').each(function() {
          var barWidth = $(this).data('value');
          $(this).css("width", barWidth + "%");
          $('.graph-bar i').each(function() {
             $(this).text(barWidth);
          });
        });
   });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: replace it by html().Hope it will be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.graph-bar').each(function() {    
          var barWidth = $(this).data('value');    
          $(this).css("width", barWidth + "%");
          $(this).find('i').text(barwidth);     
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code what I get is there is only one i tag in each graph bar, so looping through i tag is not what you need. Just do it normally in one line after setting the css.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.graph-bar').each(function() { 
      var barWidth = $(this).data('value');  
      $(this).css("width", barWidth + "%");
      $(this).children().text(barWidth);     
  });
});
```

Here's the working example in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ohwdhdmr/3/

Answer (score 1):

the following running result you want to make:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU37i.png)

### code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.graph-bar').each(function() { 
          var barWidth = $(this).data('value'); 
          if(parseInt(barWidth,10) < 40) {
           $(this).addClass('lt');
          } else if(parseInt(barWidth,10) < 60) {
           $(this).addClass('md');
          } else {
            $(this).addClass('gt');
          }
          $(this).css("width", barWidth + "%");
          $(this).find('i').text(barWidth);     
     });
});
```

```css
.graph-bar-bg{
  background-color: #bdd;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.graph-bar{
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.lt{
    background-color: #1EAB15;
}
.md{
    background-color: #A9AB15;
}
.gt{
     background-color: #D81C1C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph-bar-bg">
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="78"><i></i></span>
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="20"><i></i></span>
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="50"><i></i></span>
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="10"><i></i></span>
  <span class="graph-bar" data-value="60"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zhan! Really appreciate the additional parseInt related lines of code, it's very useful.